# I can't see my remote branch

Tags: git

While waiting for the sysadmin to set up the gerrit repo, I made my own branch.  He just now sent me the address of the repo. I set it for origin and somehow pushed my last commit. **Cloning the repo works fine**, however `git branch -r` returns nothing. What is going on here?

```
$ git init
# made some comits    
git config remote.origin.url ssh://gerrit.mm-sol.com/branchname

$ git push origin SH1-of-my-last-commit:master    
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master    
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor  
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.  
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit.mm-sol.com/apps/phone-shaker'  

$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 85, done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 20.95 KiB, done.  
Total 85 (delta 49), reused 0 (delta 0)  
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (49/49)   
remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)  
To ssh://gerrit.mm-sol.com/branchname  
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Try `git fetch origin` and then `git branch -r` again.

Comment: If you have not pushed anything there yet, the cloned repo wont show any branch. It should have after the last command, though.

Comment: @Amber: `git push` updates both remote and remote tracking (the local branch pointer, matching the remote) branch pointers

Comment: @Amber,  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD. Still git branch -r returns nothing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

and then try `git branch -r` again.

In the future when setting up remotes, it's preferable to use the following command instead of `git config`:

```
git remote add <remotename> <remoteurl>
```

e.g.

```
git remote add origin ssh://gerrit.mm-sol.com/branchname
```

This will automatically  set up both the `url` and `fetch` configuration.

Comment: Another problem solved :) I am used to cloning repo-s and was doing this thing for the first time. Tahnks a lot, Amber!

Answer (score 1):

Try to `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Ah, right. If the `git remote add` were used, it would have been done, but the setup command was somewhat incomplete: `git config remote.origin.url ...`

Comment: mvitkov@mms:~/projects/myproject$ git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date. However, git branch -r still returns nothing!