# Can't see remote branch, problems with .git/config?

Tags: git, branch, config

For some reason I can't see new branches that one my team has entered, I am 99% sure the branch exists as I can see it in Bitbucket's UI.

I have a feeling it may be because my .git/config file is not correct.

At the moment I have this...

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/testing:refs/remotes/origin/testing
    fetch = +refs/heads/uat:refs/remotes/origin/uat
    fetch = +refs/heads/release-1.9:refs/remotes/origin/release-1.9
```

I have tried "git remote update" & "git fetch origin" but both fail to get the new branch

I remember "starring" the issue here [I can't see my remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578665/i-cant-see-my-remote-branch), and changing my config to something like the following on an older laptop

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

I would really like to know the underlying reason as to why my config file is in it's current state...perhaps I am not creating branches in the correct way?

In general when creating new branches I am doing something like

```
git checkout -b issue-1001
```

And then the following to share my branch

```
git push origin issue-1001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fetch` refspec you have in place is only fetching `master`, `testing`, `uat`, and `release-1.9`.  As a result, any other branches pushed up to the remote repo, are ignored and are never brought to your local repo.  The refspec on your laptop:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

says to fetch *all* branches from the remote repository, so any new branches would be visible to you.

The short form is that if you want to see the new branches, then you need to use a refspec like the one above.

BTW, the way you're creating branches looks fine. :-)

Comment: That makes sense, I have recently created a new branch actually but it's not in my refspec so really curious as to how those refspec even get created.

Comment: The clone command generally creates the default refspec.  You can add more at clone time using the `-c` option, but it's often easier to just edit the `.git/config` to change the `fetch` line or add another.  I think one thing to remember is that creating branches creates a *reference*.  But the refspec for fetching is about which *remote references to expose*.