# How can I tell Git to ignore certain branches when fetching/pulling?

Tags: git, git-config, git-fetch

Currently, when I pull, I get changes from all the branches:

```
$ git pull
remote: ...
Unpacking objects: ...
From ssh://github.com/...
   a69d94d..a2019da  master     -> origin/master
   b684d4a..b8819dc  develop    -> origin/develop
 + 263c644..f1c1894  gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages  (forced update)
Updating a69d94d..a2019da
```

I like this behavior, but I don't need to get content from the `gh-pages` branch as that only contains generated content. How do I configure Git to fetch from all branches except some (`gh-pages`). I'd also like to avoid ever seeing `gh-pages` in my list of local branches.

Comment: Does the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository help?  Though, it is only about fetch.

Comment: Wouldn't configuring the `remote.origin.fetch` as I mention in my answer  include only the branch you want, and not `gh-branch`?

Comment: @VonC yes, but wouldn't have I have to do this manually do this for every remote branch?

Comment: The idea is to do it for the only remote branch you want to work on. It will ignore all the others.

Comment: @VonC what I like about my current behavior of `git pull` is that it automatically adds new remote branches.

Comment: So you want all remote branches, *except* one or two?

Comment: @VonC Yes, I'd like to have every remote branch except `gh-pages`. Maybe a script is in order...

Comment: Indeed. I wouldn't know how to do this kind of fetch exclusion with one git command.

Answer (score 7):

You could modify your config to fetch only one branch:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

With

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If you have more than one branch, you can add several fetch directives to fetch those (except `gh-pages`, the one you don't want to fetch)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18205776/6309) for an example of a multiple-branch fetch.

I understand this isn't a solution that scales well, but a fetch refspec doesn't support the normal exclusion syntax (like `^<rev>`: see "[Specifying ranges](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges)").

There is a way to hide a certain refspec, introduced in git 1.8.2: [commit daebaa7, "upload/receive-pack: allow hiding ref hierarchies"](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daebaa78137d59693a808c1f0bdec0ecb40fc12e), but that is on the remote side, not one the client side.

Comment: The question is about **skipping** one and not including only one.

Comment: @manojlds wouldn't including one skip the other? Basically, you need to list the branches you want to fetch.

Comment: @manojlds This answer *should* work, but I'll wait to see if anyone else has a less manual solution. I branch often.

Comment: You can make an alias that will push and add pushed branch to your fetch config.