# Git fetch not updating origin/master

Tags: git

When I do `git fetch`, nothing happens, even though I can see that my `origin/master` is behind the one on GitHub. The only output I get from `git fetch` is

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:myname/myrepo
 * branch            master      -> FETCH_HEAD
```

The output I want is

```
$ git fetch
From github.com:myname/myrepo
   6a6a103..77edb9d  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      feature    -> origin/feature
```

when I run `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote
From git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git
77edb9d40be3a75bd25288ab375ef16e009267fa        HEAD
77edb9d40be3a75bd25288ab375ef16e009267fa        refs/heads/master      <-- latest
9f2c06129eefef3f1cdc96499058d7b58e2ad0b6        refs/heads/feature
```

but `git show-ref` gives me

```
$ git show-ref
e4d894a2db19c3dbbdb946b25142c981695e0790 refs/heads/master
9f2c06129eefef3f1cdc96499058d7b58e2ad0b6 refs/heads/feature
6a6a10322110a690044e267eb7644613057dd932 refs/remotes/origin/master    <-- old!
```

Why won't `git fetch` do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If there is a way to fix this via the command line?

You can use a [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) command (to [fetch again all remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207676/6309)):

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

Answer (score 3):

`origin`'s refspec is hosed. The refspec is the part of the remote configuration that tells git what to fetch and how. It is described in more detail [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section/).

In `.git/config` there is a section

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git
```

This should look like

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If there is a way to fix this via the command line, I am not aware of it. I also do not know why this happened.